# Sumar valores obtenidos en javascript

Tags: javascript

Buen día.

Como puedo realizar la suma de valores obtenidos desde JSON e interpretados con JS. En el codigo siguiente obtengo mis datos traidos con json y los recorro con el for para mostrarlos, entre ellos el `campo datos[dato].bultos` requiero sumar su valores obtenidos.

```
 for(var dato in datos) {
    var temp = [datos[dato].referencia,datos[dato].estilo,datos[dato].bultos,datos[dato].piezas

_teoricas,datos[dato].total_piezas];
                data.push(temp);

var totales = parseInt(datos[dato].bultos); //Aqui quiero los mis valores como el comentario  var totales = [18,1,153,1,62,1];
// var totales = [18,1,153,1,62,1];
var valor = 0;

                for( var i=0; i < totales.length;i++){
                              valor += totales[i];


                    }
                  console.log(valor);

}
```

En mi `var totales` obtengo mis valores mostrándolo con `console.log: var totales = parseInt(datos[dato].bultos);`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi `for (var i=0; i < totales.length;i++)` realizo el proceso para realizar la suma y obtengo como resultado es 0.

Comment: tal vez utilizando `valor+=parseInt(totales[i].value)` resuelva tu problema

Comment: @Ever , el valor que muestra en la imagen de `console.log` es el resultado de imprimir la variable `totales` o  el resultado de hacer un `console.log(totales[i].value)` en cada iteración del for . si es esto último mi respuesta no es acertada

Comment: @Dev.Joel es el valor es de mi var totales lo que se muestra en mi imagen, el valor o valores de mi var totales los quiero pasarl a un array de tipo number ya que el resto de mi función es correcta para sumar.

Comment: @Ever entonces mi respuesta debería funcionar. Leer con atención la segunda parte con respecto a la propiedad `value`

Comment: @Ever su edición corrige justamente lo que propuse en mi respuesta y ahora su pregunta está enfocada a otro error lo cuál las respuestas anteriores carecen de sustento. Igual añadí una respuesta con su edición.

Answer (score 2):

Los valores de tu json no son del tipo numérico, es por eso que al intentar hacer la suma retorna NAN. Para comvertirlos a tipo numerico puedes:

> Convertirlos con la funcción `Number()` 
>   `let numero = Number("123")`
>
> Anteponer entre parentecis el operador `+`, es el equivalente a la
>   función Number()`let numero = +("123")`
>
> **Nota** La conversión se realizará siempre y cuando el string solo
>   contenga números y esté libre de espacios.

Y usando tu función de suma, pudieras aplicar con:

```
for( var i=0; i < totales.length;i++)
    valor += +(totales[i].value);
```

Answer (score 2):

El error es sencillo, está sumando cadenas en lugar de números, haría falta un `cast` antes de realizar la operación ya sea con `parseInt`  o `parseFloat`.

Según el formato de `array` no es correcto acceder a `value` ya que no posee esta propiedad , si no directamente al elemento para obtener su valor ya que es en esta parte donde puede obtener el error `NAN` ya que estaría obteniendo `undefined`

```js
var totales = ["18","1","153","1","62","1"];
var valor = 0;
for( var i=0; i < totales.length;i++){
    valor += parseInt(totales[i]);
}

console.log(valor);
```

Otra opción sería utilizar [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) para realizar la suma

```js
var totales = ["18","1","153","1","62","1"];
let suma = totales.reduce((ant,act)=> { return parseInt(ant)+parseInt(act) })
console.log(suma);
```

> realizo el proceso para realizar la suma y obtengo como resultado es
>   0.

La función [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt) recibe por parámetro una cadena no un array  , lo cuál al hacer `parseInt(array)` , solo convertirá el primer elemento y ese será retornado

```js
var totales = parseInt(["18","1","153","1","62","1"]);
console.log(totales);
```

Por lo tanto `totales.length` siempre será `undefined` ya que no tienen está propiedad los valores numéricos , y jamás entrará al `for`

Por favor seguir el primer ejemplo de mi respuesta y funcionará , hacer el cast a cada elemento iterado en el for.

Comment: for clasico es  casi siempre mas rapido, pero si tienes elementos vacios como [2,3, null, 3] el for in y las otras funcionalidades de JavaScript seran mas rapidas en comparacion con el for ya que omiten el/los null